# bash: adduser: command not found [Debian 10 Buster]

Tags: debian, user-management

What is the way to add new users in Debian 10 Buster? I tried adduser but this appears to be missing.

`> adduser myuser`

> bash: adduser: command not found

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, specifying the full path might help `/usr/sbin/adduser` or running with a root environment

Comment: Hi @IronMan, thanks, it work. I add in the file ~/.bashrc the next line: 
export PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:usr/local/sbin"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you basic commands ain't installed on your OS.

> sudo apt install adduser

should fix the thing